# why is null == 0 outputs false since both are falsey values?

Tags: javascript, comparison, equality

When I run

```
null == 0
```

or

```
0 == null
```

both outputs false even when both are falsey values, why?

Comment: Why does `1 == 2` output false even though they're both truthy values?

Comment: @Juhana Because their type is same and as per spec http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison, (clause 3) if the type is same, then strict equality is performed

Comment: _If an object is compared with a number or string, JavaScript attempts to return the default value for the object. Operators attempt to convert the object to a primitive value, a String or Number value, using the valueOf and toString methods of the objects. If this attempt to convert the object fails, a runtime error is generated._ As _Bergi_ said, _`Null` and `Undefined` Types are strictly equal to themselves and abstractly equal to each other.[Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)_

Comment: Why does `1 == "2"` output false even though they're both truthy values and their type is not the same?

Comment: Try `console.log(false==null)`... it returns "false", not "true".

Comment: @gurvinder372: If you are already looking at the spec, you clearly can see that `null` only compares equal to itself and `undefined` but nothing else, can't you?

Comment: `==` parses both operand to same type. So when you try to do `0==null`, its similar to `0 === parseInt(null)` which is `0 === NaN`. So its falsey.

Comment: @Bergi yes Rayon already pointed that out. I should have realized that null should be treated as object (Clause 10 and 11)

Comment: @Juhana I have already got the answer, but `1=="2"` is false for a different reason. It still first evaluates to `1==2` then false

Comment: @gurvinder372: No, `null` is not treated as an object. It's handled in clauses 3, 4 and 5 (and 12)

Comment: You've missed my point – the initial premise that comparing falsey values with `==` is always true is wrong.

Comment: @Bergi I don't think so, 10 and 11 checks the `typeof` which is `"object"`hence they are relevant. 3,4, and 5 are not checking for `0 == null` scenario.

Comment: @gurvinder372: They do check [*Type(x)*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values), not [`typeof x`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-typeof-operator). `0 == null` is handled in clause 12, the only comparisons with `null` that yield true are in clause 3, 4 and 5.

Comment: @Juhana But you gave examples of comparing non-falsey values, didn't you?

Answer (score -1):

== doesn't only check for values but also for types (and not in the same way that ===)
You can see more details here : [The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3)

Comment: if u use === also still false only

Comment: == only checks the value === only will check datatype

Comment: nope, you can check here and you'll see that several type check are performed by the == operator : http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3